# I somehow can't stop my setTimeout() loop

Tags: javascript, function, settimeout, cleartimeout

So i have a major `function` which triggers another `function` every 2 - 17 seconds but when I try to stop it with `clearTimeout()` it just goes on and completely ignores the `clearTimeout()`.

So this is my major function:

```
var itemTimer;
var stopTimeout;

function major (){
    var itemTime = Math.floor(Math.random() * 15000) + 2000;
    itemTimer = setTimeout('items()', itemTime);    
    stopTimeout = setTimeout('major()',itemTime);
}
```

And this is my stop timeout function:

```
function stopTimer() {
    clearTimeout(itemTimer);
    clearTimeout(stopTimeout);
}
```

Thank you for helping

Comment: Where and how do you call `stopTimer`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `setTimeout()` is being called incorrectly; you're invoking `items()` and `major()`. Instead, you need to pass them as functions to be invoked.

Don't pass the brackets to the parameters, and don't wrap the parameters in quote marks.

Instead of:

```
itemTimer = setTimeout('items()', itemTime);    
stopTimeout = setTimeout('major()',itemTime);
```

You're looking for:

```
itemTimer = setTimeout(items, itemTime);
stopTimeout = setTimeout(major, itemTime);
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: While `setTimeout(items, itemTime)` is the preferred syntax, these two ways of setting a timeout are more-or-less equivalent. This isn’t the issue.

Comment: Ok thank you didn't know that since I'm relativly new to this site:D

Answer (score 1):

I think your timeouts are stacking up. As soon as `major` gets called once, the variables `itemTimer` and `stopTimeout` get reassigned a new timeout reference. So there will be no way to clear the timeouts that were previously set. If this is the case it should be an easy fix though. Just call `stopTimer` as very first statement in `major`:

```
function major (){
    stopTimer();
    var itemTime = Math.floor(Math.random() * 15000) + 2000;
    itemTimer = setTimeout('items()', itemTime);    
    stopTimeout = setTimeout('major()',itemTime);
}
```